# Shopware 6.5 Add custom line item not working any more

Tags: shopware6

In one of my plugins I add a custom line item to the cart.

After updating to Shopware 6.5, the offcanvas cart still opens, but it remains empty.
Taking a look at the database, an item is created in the cart table, though.

Has anything changed with version 6.5 regarding adding line items to the cart?

Here is the code I use in the controller (I need to create and add the line item in controller because I want to create line item after link click on my custom add to cart link.):

```php
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\SalesChannel\CartService;

[...]

 /**
     * @var CartService
     */
    private $cartService;

[...]


private function createOrUpdateLineItem(
        array $data,
        SalesChannelContext $context,
        ProductEntity $product,
        ?string $lineItemId = null
    ): Response {
        $cart = $this->cartService->getCart( $context->getToken(), $context );
        $tmp  = $data;

        $lineItemId = $lineItemId ?? Uuid::randomHex();
        $returnUrl  = $this->extractReturnUrl( $data['NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_1:132'][0] ?? '' );

        foreach ( $cart->getLineItems() as $lineItem )
        {
            if ( $lineItem->getPayloadValue( 'myId' ) === $lineItemId )
            {
                $this->cartService->remove( $cart, $lineItem->getId(), $context );
            }
        }
        //if (isset($tmp['NEW_ITEM-PRICE'])) {
            foreach ( $tmp['NEW_ITEM-PRICE'] as $key => $price )
            {
                if ( $price === '0' )
                {
                    continue;
                }

                $longtext     = $tmp['NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_' . $key . ':132'][0] ?? null;
                $productData  = $product->getTranslated();
                $myItemData = [];

                foreach ( $data as $name => $values )
                {
                    if ( strstr( $name, 'NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_' ) )
                    {
                        $myItemData['NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT'] = $longtext;
                        continue;
                    }

                    $myItemData[$name] = $values[$key];
                }

                $lineItem = new LineItem(
                    $product->getId(),
                    LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE,
                    $product->getId(),
                    (int) @$tmp['NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY'][$key]
                );

                $lineItem->setId( Uuid::randomHex() );
                $lineItem->setStackable( true );
                $lineItem->setRemovable( true );
                $lineItem->setPayloadValue( 'myId', $lineItemId );
                $lineItem->setPayloadValue( 'configurationDiscount', @$productData['customFields']['my_discount'] );
                $lineItem->setPayloadValue( 'configurationPrice', (float) $price );
                $lineItem->setPayloadValue( 'myData', json_encode( $myItemData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );
                $lineItem->setPayloadValue( 'myDataFull', json_encode( $data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );
                $lineItem->setPayloadValue( 'returnUrl', $returnUrl );

                $additionalProducts = [];
                /** Collect all other names + descriptions */
                foreach ( array_keys( $tmp['NEW_ITEM-PRICE'] ) as $index )
                {
                    if ( $index === $key )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $name        = $tmp['NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION'][$index];
                    $description = $tmp['NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_' . $index . ':132'][0] ?? null;

                    if ( $name )
                    {
                        $additionalProducts[] = [
                            'name'        => $name,
                            'description' => $description
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        //}

        $configuratorDescription = $this->buildDescription( $longtext, $additionalProducts );

        if ( $configuratorDescription )
        {
            $lineItem->setPayloadValue( 'configurationDescription', $configuratorDescription );
        }

        $this->cartService->add( $cart, $lineItem, $context );

        return $this->renderStorefront(
            '@MyUi/storefront/page/my-add.html.twig',
            []
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced all your variables by static values and found no issues. Did you do any debugging at all yet?

I assume the endpoint renders the template as expected and as such no exception is thrown, which should be the case if the quantity ended up being `0` for instance.

Make sure the product is available on its own. E.g. if the stock is limited, is it in stock then? In your custom endpoint cart errors may not appear in the frontend as they would in the default endpoints for altering the cart. Debug if the cart has collected errors when the item was added:

```php
$cart = $this->cartService->add($cart, $lineItem, $this->context);
dd($cart->getErrors());
```

Comment: Yes, I output the line item data for example which looked good to me.

    dd($cart->getErrors());

does not give any errors:

    PconController.php on line 260:
    Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Error\ErrorCollection {#4072 ▼
    #extensions: []
    #elements: []
    }

Comment: I can confirm that the product is available on his own, is active and has stock.

Comment: Using the shopware default theme the issue persists.

Comment: I just realized that I was the original author of that plugin  I don't think there's anything wrong with the method. Adding items this way definitely works. I think you might want to look at the cart processor at `OverwrittenPriceCollector` if that is still there. There could've been some breaking changes in the price calculation, which cause the item to immediately become invalidated. To verify, try commenting out the payload setter for `pconData`, as the processor should skip the item if it's not set. Then see if the item is added again.

Comment: Hehe, I already heared of you and nice to meet you this way : ) Will follow your hint regarding the OverwrittenPriceCollector then and let you know. Thank you! 

Comment: Just tried to comment out the setter for pconData but the item is not added again.

Comment: When trying to log something within the OverwrittenPriceCollector no log is created btw.

Comment: Do you have any more hints?